# retrieve values from the same record from a field odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I will want to retrieve different values ​from a chosen field. Let me explain:
I have this class:

```
class SchoolWebServices(models.Model):

    _name = 'ecole.webservices'

    name = fields.Char(string='Nom')
    code_produit = fields.Char(string='Produit')
    code_CDG = fields.Char(string='Centre de Gestion')
    code_Catalog = fields.Char(string='Catalogue Produits')
```

I have this other class:

```
class ResPartner_school(models.Model):

    _name = 'ecole.partner.school'
    _order = 'id desc'

    half_pension_name = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="ecole.webservices",
                                    string="Lieu")
```

And I have a function who is in the class: ecole.partner.school

```
    @api.multi
    def create_compte_cantine(self):

        print "Inscription réussie"

        get_halfpension_name = self.half_pension_name.id


        if get_halfpension_name:

            code_Catalog = self.env['ecole.webservices'].code_Catalog
```

I get the id of `half_pension_name` in my variable `get_halfpension_name` but I wish to recover the `code_Catalog` of the same recording too. How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use dot-notation to retrieve the value:

```py
@api.multi
def create_compte_cantine(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    if self.half_pension_name:
        code_Catalog = self.half_pension_name.code_Catalog
```

Try to stay in the "rules" of the [Odoo guideline](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/guidelines.html). For example a Many2one relation field should be end with _id -> `half_pension_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="ecole.webservices", string="Lieu")`

Comment: Thank you for your help and advices. What does the ensure_one () function mean?

Comment: Look into the documentation ;-)

Comment: I have find. Thanks you